# JQM Buttons in a row?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, button, jqueryi-ui-buttonset

i'm trying to get 7 buttons in a vertical row, on the left of my viewport in, the first 3 buttons look fine just need to move them down but then the other 4 are not inline with the top 3 heres my code,

```
<div class="ui-grid-b">
                   <div class="ui-block-a">
                        <div class="ui-block-a"><a href="#" data-role="button" data-theme="a" data-inline="true">btn1</a></div></div>
                        <div class="ui-block-a"><a href="#" data-role="button" data-theme="a" data-inline="true">btn2</a></div></div>
                        <div class="ui-block-a"><a href="#" data-role="button" data-theme="a" data-inline="true">btn3</a></div></div>
                <div class="ui-grid-b">
                   <div class="ui-block-a">
                        <div class="ui-block-a"><a href="#" data-role="button" data-theme="a" data-inline="true">btn4</a></div></div>
                        <div class="ui-block-a"><a href="#" data-role="button" data-theme="a" data-inline="true">btn5</a></div>
                        <div class="ui-block-a"><a href="#" data-role="button" data-theme="a" data-inline="true">btn6</a></div>
                        <div class="ui-block-a"><a href="#" data-role="button" data-theme="a" data-inline="true">btn7</a></div>
```

[image]

Comment: You don't need all those blocks, one `ui-grid` and one `ui-block` will do the job http://fiddle.jshell.net/Palestinian/564VX/ also, you can do them vertically using `data-role=controlgroup`. http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.1/dist/demos/widgets/buttons/#button-vertical-group

Comment: yeah that doesent work for me it just puts them side by side on two rows, i'll attach screen now

Comment: check this now http://fiddle.jshell.net/Palestinian/564VX/

Comment: thats great its working but how can i move it down the page a few px's? without just using <br>'s?? thanks allot :)

Comment: Sorry, ill get you a complete answer tomorrow :)

Comment: its fine i've just used <br>'s and it looks great, i would like to know how i can target each button via css

Comment: Ok buddy :) give each one a class if you want. You will be using classes later on in JS to attach events for each button ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need one `ui-grid` and one `ui-block-a`.

> **[Demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Palestinian/564VX/)**

```html
<div class="left-btns ui-grid-a">
  <div class="ui-block-a">
    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-theme="a" data-inline="true">btn1</a><br/>
    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-theme="a" data-inline="true">btn2</a><br/>
    .....
</div>
```